# Questions not about code

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Considering that he's talking about a programming tool is this question ok?

[ServiceStack C# Client Libraries license](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182195/servicestack-c-sharp-client-libraries-license)

Usually I see SO as a community for questions about specific code problems

Comment: The question is not about a tool but about licensing. Off-topic.

Comment: Which is the right flag to use?

Comment: Just wait a sec, it is closed just about.... now :)

Comment: You could to the same as someone else already did: Close -> Offtopic -> Other and then provide a comment.

Comment: @Tom Not without having 3k rep.

Comment: Oh okay, i tought they did Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with programming)

Comment: @MarcoSalerno That doesn't accomplish much of anything if there are already close votes on the post, but if there were none, then yes, that would be the right flag.

Comment: Anyway i think there should be a flag for particular cases like this

Comment: @Servy when i did this post it was opened

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Even if it's open, if there are already *any* close votes on the post, then flagging doesn't do anything.  Flagging a post for closure only has value if there isn't even a single close vote yet.

Comment: And had 0 flags

Comment: (that is probably a bit of cross-communication here, I've also confused flagging and close voting in the past).

Comment: Well the offtopic flag is a closing request